# Run parts of a batch file based on the day of the week

Tags: file, parsing, batch-file, dayofweek

I am running a dos batch file in SQL Server Agent job.  I have 34 steps in the batch file.  All steps run every day EXCEPT step 31.  It only runs on Tuesday.  I could setup another SQL Agent Job, but that seems like overkill.  How can I query the system for the day of the week in the batch file in order to run Step 31 on Tuesday only?  I tried the below code but had not luck.

```
For /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%A in ('Date /t') do @( 
Set DayName=%%A 
) 

if('%DayName:~0,3%' equ 'Tue') <run step 31>
```

When I echo '%DayName:~0,3%' it displays 'Tue'

Comment: What was the result? You could probably simplify the script by using `%DATE:~0,3%` instead of the FOR loop.

Comment: @hall.stephenk....good idea.  I like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek
```

Returning "2" is Tuesday.

Comment: As seen here:  http://serverfault.com/questions/94824/finding-day-of-week-in-batch-file-windows-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback.  I found the issue.  It was the parens in the if statement.  Once I removed them it worked fine.  I also removed the single quotes.

This works

```
if %DayName:~0,3% equ Tue
```

This also work:

```
if '%DATE:~0,3%' equ 'Tue'
```

These don't work

```
if %DATE:~0,3% equ 'Tue'
if (%DATE:~0,3% equ Tue)
```

Comment: It was actually the quotes that were the cause of the problem. `if %DATE:0,3% equ "Tue" echo True` outputs nothing, while `if %DATE:0,3% equ Tue echo True` outputs `True`.

Comment: Why do I get "201" instead of "Tue" ?

Comment: @Ken....cool deal. thanks for the clarification. And actually it's both. if (%DATE:~0,3% equ Tue)  echo True outputs nothing

Comment: @Francis...not sure.  2 would be the Tuesday part?  Maybe your system clock setting is different?

Comment: @Francis:  I'd guess you're in a locale where `%DATE%` starts with the year first (2012).  Therefore the first 3 characters of your date variable are "201" instead of "Tue".  This issue is why your solution is more robust than this one.

Comment: @indiv...agreed Francis' answer is more robust in general.  My answer works for our current need.  Thanks for the feedback